# What is the Cartesian Product of two nonempty sets, one of which includes Ø as an element?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{a, b, \{\emptyset\}\}$. Does $A \times B = \{\emptyset\}$ or is it something more like $A \times B = \{ (1, a), (1, b), \{\emptyset\}, (2, a), (2, b),\{\emptyset\}, (3, a), (3, b), \{\emptyset\} \}$?

Comment: The set containing the empty set and the empty set are different sets. $\{ \emptyset \} \not = \emptyset $

Comment: @ΘΣΦ GenSan I think your edit removed the confusion that the asker was having and changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: @Q the Platypus Yeah, my bad. I returned it to the original.

Comment: White of those two sets do you think includes $\emptyset$ as an element? Certainly $A$ doesn't have $\emptyset$ as an element, assuming that natural numbers are realized as sets in the usual way. But $\emptyset$ might be an element of $B,$ because for all we know maybe $a=\emptyset$ or $b=\emptyset.$

Answer (score 2):

Neither are correct, but the second is closer. It should be
$$A \times B = \left\{ (1, a), (1, b), (1, \{\emptyset\}), (2, a), (2, b), (2,\{\emptyset\}), (3, a), (3, b), (3,\{\emptyset\}) \right\}.$$
After all, $\{\emptyset\}$ is an element just like any another.

Also, $\{\emptyset\}$ is **not** the empty set. It is a set that contains only the empty set. Make sure you are familiar with the distinction.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the question is written as B = { Ø, 1, 2, 3} instead of B = { {Ø}, 1, 2, 3} ?

Comment: Yes, it does. You would then get $$A\times B = \left\{(1,a),(1,b),(1,\emptyset),(2,a),(2,b),(2,\emptyset),(3,a),(3,b),(3,\emptyset)\right\}$$ You have to convince yourself that $\emptyset$ or $\{\emptyset\}$ are not special in this context; they are elements just like anything else.

Answer (score 2):

> $$(A \times B):= \{({\color{Red}y},{\color{green}z})| {\color{Red}y}
>  \in A \wedge {\color{green}z} \in B\}$$

By definition we have also following:

$$\begin{array}{}
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
(A \times B)&{\color{green}a} \in B&  {\color{green}b} \in B& {\color{green}\{{\color{green}\emptyset{\color{green}\}}}} \in B\\ \hline
{\color{Red}1} \in A&({\color{Red}1},{\color{green}a})&({\color{Red}1},{\color{green}b})&({\color{Red}1},{\color{green}\{{\color{green}\emptyset{\color{green}\}}}} )\\
{\color{Red}2} \in A&({\color{Red}2},{\color{green}a})&({\color{Red}2},{\color{green}b})&({\color{Red}2},{\color{green}\{{\color{green}\emptyset{\color{green}\}}}} )\\
{\color{Red}3} \in A&({\color{Red}3},{\color{green}a})&({\color{Red}3},{\color{green}b})&({\color{Red}3},{\color{green}\{{\color{green}\emptyset{\color{green}\}}}} )\\
\end{array}&&&
\end{array}$$
 $$(A \times B)=\{({\color{Red}1},{\color{green}a}),({\color{Red}1},{\color{green}b}),({\color{Red}1},{\color{green}\{{\color{green}\emptyset{\color{green}\}}}} ),({\color{Red}2},{\color{green}a}),({\color{Red}2},{\color{green}b}),({\color{Red}2},{\color{green}\{{\color{green}\emptyset{\color{green}\}}}} ),({\color{Red}3},{\color{green}a}),({\color{Red}3},{\color{green}b}),({\color{Red}3},{\color{green}\{{\color{green}\emptyset{\color{green}\}}}} )\}$$